# How to use functions in a react props to transform the given props into a result to show?

Tags: reactjs, function

I'm a beginner in React, and I tried to react-ify a JS project into a react one.

The JS one does work, it's a simple converter that converts an energy input into a timer, for a mobile gacha game (Like 1 energy every 8 mins, so if you need 120 you'll have to wait (mojo function convertor) xx hours and minutes.

Here how I thought it :https://gyazo.com/68ae447f389406735cd56384f70bba5f.png (cannot directly post the picture because i'm new to stackoverflow)

(Yes, sorry, it's in French :D)

I spent some time to understand the states, props and context, so I can pass the Input from component 2 to component 3 (the output) as a prop , but what I would need is to be able use some functions to convert this raw props input into several information I'd need (a timer count, a real time date too, as I did in JS).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BlocInitialOutput extends Component {

    amountOfHours = 0
    amountOfTime = 0
    resinNeeded = 0
    expr = "" (supposedly an hour)
    realTimedays = 0
    
    missingResinToTime() {
    
            this.resinNeeded = 160 - this.props.value;
            this.amountOfTime = (this.resinNeeded * 8); // amountOfTime = minutes
            // this.convertToHours(this.amountOfTime) etc there are many more functions but I kept it simple for the exemple
      
    }

    render() {
       
        return (
            <div>
            <h5> Full reload {this.realTimedays === 1 && <span> tomorrow </span>}
            at {this.expr} </h5>

            
                  
      <h5> You'll need {this.realTimedays === 1 && <span> {this.realTimedays} day, </span>}
       {this.amountOfHours} hours and {this.amountOfTime} minutes to reach xxx energy </h5>

           

                TestValue : {this.props.value}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export {BlocInitialOutput};
```

I kept it simple for this exemple, but there would be, as you can imagine, more functions here. The input verification already occurs in my component 2 and is functionnal, I only struggle to convert everything in that "output" component.

I already tried to call my function within the render and before the return like this :

```
render() {  

   missingResinToTime()


        return (
            <>blablabla</>
              );
```

But I only got a supposedly infinite load as my app wouldn't start at all.

How could I convert my props into the different data I would need to make it operational ? Is that even possible, react-speaking ?

I'm afraid i'm missing something in React.

Thanks in Advance,
Meren

Comment: Try creating a jsfiddle with your component, it will help to find a solution

Comment: If there is data _outside_ of your component that affects the UI - it's a prop.
If there is data _inside_ of your component that affects the UI - it's a state.

I don't see you use state. At least I don't see you call `this.setState` anywhere. Note, `setState` is the only appropriate way to change state values.

Comment: `render() {  

   missingResinToTime()` doesn't work because it should be `this.missingResinToTime()`.

Comment: I thank you, the "this." hint you gave me made me realize that as I didn't use a constructor on this component, I couldn't bind the function and therefore use it properly later. I'm almost done, spamming console logs tells me I'm on the good way to realize what I was planning, I only need to find a way to render it properly now !